# Lifetime of self embedded in Self, not &'a self

Tags: rust

Below I have

```
impl<'a, T> AsPolyIterator<'a, T> for MyPolynomial<'a, T> {
    fn as_poly_iterator(
        &self
    ) -> Result<
```

which shouldn't need `&'a self` because the `'a` already comes from `MyPolynomial<'a, T>`. Also, I should pass `&'a[T]` in `PolyIterator::new` in the line

`let iterator = PolyIterator::new(self.coefficients.as_life_ref());`

but I'm getting an error saying that it wants a `&'a (dyn Mem<'a, T> + 'a)` which I have no idea why.

```
pub trait Mem<'r, T>
{
    fn as_life_ref(&'r self) -> &'r [T];
}

pub struct PolyIterator<'a, T> {
    coefficients:   &'a [T]
}

impl<'a, T> PolyIterator<'a, T> {
    pub fn new(coefficients: &'a[T]) -> PolyIterator<'a, T> {
        todo!()
    }
}

pub struct MyPolynomial<'a, T> {
    coefficients:   Box<dyn Mem<'a, T> + 'a>,
}

pub trait AsPolyIterator<'a, T> {
    fn as_poly_iterator(&'a self) -> Result<PolyIterator<'a, T>, ()>;
}

impl<'a, T> AsPolyIterator<'a, T> for MyPolynomial<'a, T> {
    fn as_poly_iterator(
        &self
    ) -> Result<
        PolyIterator<'a, T>,
        (),
    > {
        let iterator = PolyIterator::new(self.coefficients.as_life_ref());
        todo!()
    }
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c3e657136252b96cd5aca91efeaea56f

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:31:54
   |
31 |         let iterator = PolyIterator::new(self.coefficients.as_life_ref());
   |                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime defined here...
  --> src/lib.rs:26:3
   |
26 |         &self
   |         ^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:31:36
   |
31 |         let iterator = PolyIterator::new(self.coefficients.as_life_ref());
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
  --> src/lib.rs:24:6
   |
24 | impl<'a, T> AsPolyIterator<'a, T> for MyPolynomial<'a, T> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/lib.rs:31:54
   |
31 |         let iterator = PolyIterator::new(self.coefficients.as_life_ref());
   |                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `&'a (dyn Mem<'a, T> + 'a)`
              found `&(dyn Mem<'a, T> + 'a)`
```

Answer (score 1):

Your trait definition and implementation do not line up:

```
pub trait AsPolyIterator<'a, T> {
    fn as_poly_iterator(&'a self) -> Result<PolyIterator<'a, T>, ()>;
}

impl<'a, T> AsPolyIterator<'a, T> for MyPolynomial<'a, T> {
    fn as_poly_iterator(&self) -> Result<PolyIterator<'a, T>, ()> { ... }
}
```

The trait has `PolyIterator` bound to `self`, while the implementation has it bound elsewhere, these are not compatible.

---

It should definitely be `&'a self` since the `PolyIterator` is derived from `self.coefficients`, but you should use a different lifetime `'b` for `MyPolynomial` to avoid over-constraining:

```
impl<'a, 'b, T> AsPolyIterator<'a, T> for MyPolynomial<'b, T> where 'a: 'b {
    fn as_poly_iterator(&'a self) -> Result<PolyIterator<'a, T>, ()> { ... }
}
```

Mind the `where 'a: 'b` since that ensures the lifetime `'b` is larger than `'a`. See it working on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f9c15b920d8c7c5fb35296596bbb7f67).